# Jetty doesn't throw exception when I bind to already used port

Tags: scala, jetty, serversocket

I create a server using jetty, and it is weird it would not throw exception I bind it to port which is already used by another process. But it would throw exception when this used port is used by http protocol. Does that mean jetty can only detect port conflict for http protocol ? Thanks

```
  val server = new Server(pool)
  val connectors = new ArrayBuffer[ServerConnector]
  // Create a connector on port currentPort to listen for HTTP requests
  val httpConnector = new ServerConnector(
    server,
    null,
    // Call this full constructor to set this, which forces daemon threads:
    new ScheduledExecutorScheduler(s"$serverName-JettyScheduler", true),
    null,
    -1,
    -1,
    new HttpConnectionFactory())
  httpConnector.setPort(currentPort)
```

Comment: This is not Java code.

Comment: Sorry, this is scala

Answer (score 0):

Error would be produced once the `server.start()` is called.

Also note that already bound errors do not occur on some OS's (MS Windows for example).